# Workflows in Tabidoo

Tags: workflow

we are using [Tabidoo](https://tabidoo.cloud) in our company and we are quite happy about this. We manage almost all data in Tabidoo, using Workflow automation and we encountered one - perhaps small - problem. How to set anything like birthdays. Any event that is repeated on yearly basis. In Tabidoo it is possible to set every (week) Monday, every month, but there is no option for every year.

Of course we know, we can write own type script (easily), but we would prefer to have this set without programming.

Any idea? Do we lack some info? We haven't found anything in [Help](https://help.tabidoo.cloud) neither in [FAQ](https://faq.tabidoo.cloud)

thanks for any idea...

We have tried several workflow triggers, but at the end always finished with scripting....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately such option is not directly implemented in the workflows so your best option now would be to use JS. But there is a big hope that in the near future it will become part of the workflow and it will be as easy to set as the other actions in the workflow.